# Qt4: Decorating a QLineEdit (painting around it)

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, paintevent

I am trying to "decorate" a `QLineEdit`, or to be more accurate, to paint my own custom frame around it, to get the following result:

[image]

I tried to use [Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html) (CSS), but this will only enable trivial frame decorating (changing width/color/size etc...), nothing fancy like the above.

I also tried inheriting from `QLineEdit` and overriding its [`void QLineEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#paintEvent), but then I realized that reimplementing it means I will lose the `QLineEdit`s "editness" (sorry for butchering the language here) - the textbox, the cursor, and the ability to insert text.

How can I achieve the above text box?
Is this a combination of `QLabel` perfectly located behind a `QLineEdit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use composition. Create your own Widget inherited it from `QWidget`, paint what you want in `QWidget::paintEvent` and place `QLineEdit` above it. Probably you'll have to center it and use `css` for `QLineEdit` to make it  look smooth.

```
class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
explicit MyWidget(QWidget* parent = 0):
QWidget(parent),
line_edit(new QLineEdit(this))
{
     //  place line_edit in center of QWidget
}

private: 
QLineEdit* line_edit;
}
```

Or you can override `void QLineEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)` like this

```
void QLineEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
      //paint your border
      QLineEdit::paintEvent(e);
}
```

And you won't lose the `QLineEdits` "editness".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Couple more Qs: for the first suggestion; How do I do that? will my QWidget hold a QLineEdit as a data member? as a child-widget? For the second suggestion; I tried it, but the textbox took all the space and completely hide my drawings...

Comment: Ok, great! Thank you! I did that, and set the size of the parent MyWidget to be slightly bigger than the QLineEdit child (so I'll have enough space to paint around it), now how do I move the QLineEdit inside MyWidget so it will be vertically-centered?

Comment: Use some of `QLayout`s or move it manualy by calling `QWidget::setGeometry`.